# form submit function never gets called.

Tags: forms, users

My drupal form submit function is not called. validation function is called. Form name is `Mymodule_user_profile_form($form, &$form_state)`, validation function name is `Mymodule_user_profile_form_validate($form, &$form_state)` and submit function name is `Mymodule_user_profile_form_submit($form, &$form_state)`. I have studied all the previously asked questions.

This is the last portion where I declare my submit button is defined.

```
$form['profile']['profile-share']['profile-save-reset-btn']['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Spara'),
  //'#name' => 'save-profile',
);
```

I have tried like this.

```
$form['#submit'][] =  'Mymodule_user_profile_form_submit';
```

var_dump($form['#submit']); Shows the submit function but it's never called. Any Idea about this?

Comment: Where is this code at?

Comment: Is cache cleared?

Comment: Also try `array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'Mymodule_user_profile_form_submit')` instead of `$form['#submit'][] = 'Mymodule_user_profile_form_submit'`. In this case your submit will be called first in queue.

Answer (score 0):

The submit function is correct. By default, Drupal should call `Mymodule_user_profile_form_submit()` function without declared it with the '#submit' attribute. Could you publish all the code to have a deeper exploration of it?

---

Edit:

You could try this:

```
$form['profile']['profile-share']['profile-save-reset-btn']['submit']['#submit'][] =  'Mymodule_user_profile_form_submit';
```

The atrribute is in the upper side of the rendering array. The attibute should be at the same level to be fired when the submit button is pressed:

Here an example of form api reference:

```
$form['actions']['delete'] = array(

  '#type' => 'submit',

  '#value' => t('Delete'),

  '#weight' => 15,

  '#submit' => array('node_form_delete_submit'),

 );
```

You could also attach the '#submit' in the upper level if you declare '#type' as 'form'. For example:

```
$form['#type'] = 'form';
$form['#submit'] = array('your_function');
$form['first_tree']['element'] = array( ... ) ;
$form['second_tree']['element'] = array( ... ) ;
```

Comment: Rufein, I know about that. The whole form is too big to be pasted here. I am displaying this form in Mymodule_myprofile_page.tpl.php template.

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work :(

Comment: You could disable the validation step to check if submit function is called. Maybe the error is in a previous step (validation). Does it report errors when a field is not validate ?

Comment: I have disabled validation function, If validation is disabled, and email is wrong, the form says incorrect email address. print a single line in validation function, it gets displayed but submit function is trying to upset me.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you're displaying it in a .tpl file? Where is the form builder function located?

Comment: the form is built in module but  I am calling it form page.tpl through drupal_render(drupal_get_form("my form name"))

Comment: Are you altering a profile form or building your own complete form? Something funny seems to be going on. It would be very easy to diagnose this if you posted all of the code.

Comment: I am making my own form, not altering a form. The whole form is too big to be posted here. I think submit function declaration is having problem which seems correct to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If your explanation is true, this should be working as you have described.

Submit functions only run if the validate function doesn't throw any errors. What are you doing in your validation function? Try just leaving it empty and returning `TRUE` to see if submit runs.

If you have the `devel` module enabled, put a `dpm('Submit function ran');` in the submit function and likewise in the validate function.

Answer (score 0):

This code has been taken from the form api reference:

```
 $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Submit'),
  '#weight' => 15,
  '#submit' => array('Mymodule_user_profile_form_submite'),
 );
```

The above code may help you to define your submit button and it's callback function when the form is submitted.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you samir for your comment but I had fixed it at that time and it's very old post.

Answer (score 0):

In your template file, try printing the form id,form token and form build ID

```
print render($form['form_token']);
print render($form['form_id']);
print render($form['form_build_id']);
```

Even if the these values are not present,the form callbacks will not work